# Replacing #6 Ground Wire

Tags: electrical-panel, grounding

Do I need to replace #6 solid copper ground wire from Service panel to water pipes with #4 solid copper wire in 1997 construction as recommended by inspector?

Comment: I don't know about that. But a far bigger issue is to make sure that the water pipes are in fact truly grounded. All it takes is one section of pex or PVC in between sections of copper to lose continuity.

Comment: How many amps is your service? Do you have other grounding electrodes or just the water pipe bond?

Comment: 200 Amp service panel - Can't tell if there is a grounding rod outside.  Service entrance is under a deck.

Comment: @PhilZimmerman you'll get better answers if you describe the situation better.  You mention 1997 but not if  you are doing construction now to trigger new rules.  You ask if you "need" something, but that's ambiguous.  You say an inspector "recommended" which seems to deliberately avoid saying "required".   If the objective is to pass an inspection, you could tell us more about that.  OTOH if you're looking for priorities in improving your home, and asking whether a bigger plumbing bond would be a good idea, set up your question that way.  Go look under the deck, include your observations.

Comment: I think that what @jay613 is trying to say is that if the inspector says you need to, then you _need_ to or you won't pass your inspection. Whether it's "proper" or not, is a different discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Interpretation of Article 250 Part III to be a little hard to keep up with, and it seems like the members of the NFPA take great pleasure in tweaking it in every edition.

Generally the paragraph that allows maximum #6 copper to "Rod, Pipe, or Plate" electrodes is not interpreted to include water pipe, so you would need #4 copper, but not necessarily solid.

Table 250.66 (or 250.104 if just a metal piping bonding jumper) references size of feeder to the service, which you would expect a 200A service to be fed by 2/0 copper or 4/0 aluminum for the GEC. The Table shows #4 copper or #2 aluminum, 250.62 allows stranded or solid.

A metal underground water pipe also requires a supplemental electrode.

I don't have a copy of or even know what edition of the NEC was adopted locally for your location for 1997, and don't know what exceptions may have been locally enforced.